# Неправильный приоритет в PriorityQueue в Java

Tags: java, сортировка, очередь, приоритет

Не могу разобраться, почему не удается создать очередь с приоритетом на вес(`weight`) объекта: элементы должны доставаться в неубывающем виде, однако такого не происходит.

Необходимо было создать класс вершины - `Vertex` со своим весовым значением (`weight`):

```
public class Vertex implements Comparable<Vertex>{
    public char label;
    public int weight;      // Вес для вершины
    public boolean isVisited;       
    public List<Vertex> adjList;        // Список смежности
    public Vertex p;                    // Родительская вершина
    
    
    public Vertex(char label) {
        this.label = label;
        isVisited = false;
        adjList = new ArrayList<>();
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.valueOf(label);
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(Vertex o) {    
        if(this.weight == o.weight)
            return this.label - o.label;
        
        return this.weight - o.weight;
    }
}
```

Реализован интерфейс Comparable, чтобы очередь была в неубывающем виде
Далее создал класс, чтобы проверить работоспособность очереди:

```
public class PriorityTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PriorityQueue<Vertex> priorityQueue = new PriorityQueue<>();
        
        Vertex v1 = new Vertex('1');        // 0
        Vertex v2 = new Vertex('2');        // 1
        Vertex v3 = new Vertex('3');        // 2
        Vertex v4 = new Vertex('4');        // 3
        Vertex v5 = new Vertex('5');        // 4
        Vertex v6 = new Vertex('6');        // 5
        
        v1.weight = 0;
        v2.weight = Integer.MAX_VALUE; 
        v3.weight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        v4.weight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        v5.weight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        v6.weight = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
        
        priorityQueue.offer(v1);
        priorityQueue.offer(v2);
        priorityQueue.offer(v3);
        priorityQueue.offer(v4);
        priorityQueue.offer(v5);
        priorityQueue.offer(v6);
        
        v2.weight = 6;
        v3.weight = 1;
        v4.weight = 5;
        
        System.out.println("queue");
        while(priorityQueue.peek() != null) {
            Vertex v = priorityQueue.poll();
            System.out.println(v.label + " - " + v.weight);
        }
        
    }
}
```

Ожидал увидеть :

```
queue
1 - 0
3 - 1
4 - 5
2 - 6
5 - 2147483647
6 - 2147483647
```

Однако выводится:

```
queue
3 - 1
2 - 6
4 - 5
5 - 2147483647
6 - 2147483647
```

Не могу понять, в чем ошибка

Comment: Вы сперва вставляете элементы в очередь, затем меняете их значения (и порядок). Очередь ничего не знает про изменения. Так нельзя делать.

Comment: Удаляйте элемент и повторно его вставляйте при изменении